# Create an R or Python function to generate sets based on the value of C

Tags: python, r

I need help creating an R or Python function that generates sets based on the value of C. Here's an example to illustrate what I'm looking for:

For C = 2, I have 2^2 sets, including the sets: `Cl_atypique, Cl_1, Cl_2, Cl_incertains`

For C = 3, I have 2^3 sets, including the sets: `Cl_atypique, Cl_1, Cl_2, Cl_1_2, Cl_3, Cl_1_3, Cl_2_3, Cl_incertains`

For C = 4, I have 2^4 sets, including the sets: `Cl_atypique, Cl_1, Cl_2, Cl_1_2, Cl_3, Cl_1_3, Cl_2_3, Cl_1_2_3, Cl_4, Cl_1_4, Cl_2_4, Cl_1_2_4,Cl_3_4,Cl_1_3_4, Cl_2_3_4, Cl_incertains`

I would like to create an R or Python function that takes the value of C as input and returns a vector containing the sets in the specified order. This vector will be used to name a table later on.

I have this function that works, but the problem is with the order of the sets.

```
get_ensembles <- function(C) {
  ensembles <- c()
  ensembles <- c(ensembles, "Cl_atypique")
  for (i in 1:(C-1)) {
    subsets <- combn(1:C, i)
    for (j in 1:ncol(subsets)) {
      ensemble <- subsets[, j]
      ensembles <- c(ensembles, paste0("Cl_", paste0(ensemble, collapse = "_")))
    }
  }
  ensembles <- c(ensembles, "Cl_incertains")
  return(ensembles)
}
get_ensembles(3)
```

> get_ensembles(3)
> [1] "Cl_atypique"   "Cl_1"          "Cl_2"          "Cl_3"          "Cl_1_2"
> [6] "Cl_1_3"        "Cl_2_3"        "Cl_incertains"

As can be seen in the output, Cl_3 and Cl_1_2 are reversed. I can't find a solution

Thank you !

Comment: Look art `?combn`

Comment: and `itertools.combinations` for python.

Comment: Must the order be as represented above?

Comment: Yes, I need the order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in R you could do:

```r
get_ensembles <- function(C){
  cbs <- function(x,v = x[1]){
      if(length(x)<2) v
      else cbs(x[-1], c(v, x[2], paste(v, x[2], sep = '_')))
  }
  paste0('CL_', c('atypique', cbs(seq.int(C))[-2^C+1], 'incertains'))
}

get_ensembles(4)
 [1] "CL_atypique"   "CL_1"          "CL_2"          "CL_1_2"       
 [5] "CL_3"          "CL_1_3"        "CL_2_3"        "CL_1_2_3"     
 [9] "CL_4"          "CL_1_4"        "CL_2_4"        "CL_1_2_4"     
[13] "CL_3_4"        "CL_1_3_4"      "CL_2_3_4"      "CL_incertains"
```

---

You could directly convert the code above into python:

```py
import numpy as np
def get_ensembles(C):
    def cbs(x, v = np.array('1')):
        if x.size < 2 : return v
        return cbs(x[1:], np.r_[v, np.array(x[1]), 
            np.char.add(v, np.char.add('_',x[1]))])
    return np.r_[np.array('CL_atypique'),
        cbs(np.arange(1,C+1).astype(str))[:-1],
        np.array('CL_incertains')]

get_ensembles(4)
array(['CL_atypique', '1', '2', '1_2', '3', '1_3', '2_3', '1_2_3', '4',
       '1_4', '2_4', '1_2_4', '3_4', '1_3_4', '2_3_4', 'CL_incertains'],
      dtype='<U13')
```

Answer (score 2):

a python version

```py
from itertools import combinations

def get_ensembles(C):
  ensembles = ['Cl_atypique']
  ensembles_set = set()
  for numCount in range(1, C+1):
    for pickCount in range(1, C):
      for pick in combinations(range(1, numCount+1), pickCount):
        if pick not in ensembles_set:
          ensembles_set.add(pick)
          ensembles.append('Cl_'+'_'.join(map(str, pick)))
  ensembles.append('Cl_incertains')
  return ensembles
```

if you just want to iterate over the possible long list:

```py
from itertools import combinations

def get_ensembles(C):
  yield 'Cl_atypique'
  ensembles_set = set()
  for numCount in range(1, C+1):
    for pickCount in range(1, C):
      for pick in combinations(range(1, numCount+1), pickCount):
        if pick not in ensembles_set:
          ensembles_set.add(pick)
          yield 'Cl_'+'_'.join(map(str, pick))
  yield 'Cl_incertains'
```

Answer (score 1):

This Python solution provides the output you need.

```
from itertools import combinations
from pprint import pprint
import re

def parse(s):
    m = re.search(r'(?<=_)(\d+)$', s)
    return int(m.group(1))

def get_ensembles(C):
    L = []
    
    for i in range(1,C):
        for c in combinations(range(1, C+1),i):
            L.append('_'.join(['Cl', *map(str,c)]))
    
    L.sort(key=lambda x: parse(x))
    L.insert(0,'Cl_atypique')
    L += ['Cl_incertains']
    
    return L

pprint(get_ensembles(4))
```

Output is:

```
['Cl_atypique',
 'Cl_1',
 'Cl_2',
 'Cl_1_2',
 'Cl_3',
 'Cl_1_3',
 'Cl_2_3',
 'Cl_1_2_3',
 'Cl_4',
 'Cl_1_4',
 'Cl_2_4',
 'Cl_3_4',
 'Cl_1_2_4',
 'Cl_1_3_4',
 'Cl_2_3_4',
 'Cl_incertains']
```

Comment: why don't you let `parse` return the last number: `return int(re.search(r'(?<=_)(\d+)$', s).group(1))`

Comment: @rioV8 Yes you are right - nice catch. I'll have to amend my post to this simplified solution.

Comment: @rioV8 I can't create a generator for my function because of the sort altering the order returned - your solution allows that due to the order of your statements.

Comment: Strawberry Perl is a Windows build of a Perl, just like ActivePerl. /// It fully supports Perl's standard package manager CPAN. (So does ActivePerl, actually.)

Comment: @ikegami Yes, I know about Strawberry Perl but I didn't know what changes that would make to my operating system and my knowledge of unix is meager. make file etc. Active State perl worked great for me until they dropped support for installing precomplied libraries.

Comment: Again, Strawberry Perl is a Windows build of a Perl. Knowledge of unix and makes files is irrelevant.

Comment: Re "*they dropped support for installing precomplied libraries.*", They have not done that.